Error in flutter project when installing any version of supabase package
I have been getting the error below whenever i add any versions of supabase package to my flutter project
   > Failed to transform core-1.10.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find core-1.10.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.10.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.10.1/core-1.10.1.aar
   > Failed to transform core-1.10.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find core-1.10.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.10.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.10.1/core-1.10.1.aar
   > Failed to transform interpolator-1.0.0.aar (androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find interpolator-1.0.0.aar (androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/interpolator/interpolator/1.0.0/interpolator-1.0.0.aar
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/interpolator/interpolator/1.0.0/interpolator-1.0.0.jar
   > Failed to transform annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation-experimental/1.3.0/annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar

below is my app level build.gradle.
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.testing"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.testing"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}

Id be really glad if anyone could help.
and this is my pubspec.yaml
name: testing
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.3 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  #supabase_flutter: ^2.5.11
  #google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  #supabase_flutter: ^2.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
  supabase_flutter: ^2.5.4
  #file_picker: ^8.0.5
  #flutter_pdfview: ^1.3.2
  #syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^26.2.7
  #http: ^1.2.2
  #sqflite: ^2.3.3+1
  #font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  #shimmer: ^3.0.0
  #photo_view: ^0.15.0
  #image_picker: ^1.1.2
  #timeago: ^3.7.0
  #postgres: ^3.2.1
  #transparent_image: ^2.0.1
  #cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  #loading_animation_widget: ^1.2.1
  #animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^1.3.3
  #connectivity_plus: ^6.0.4
  #lottie: ^3.1.2
  #syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^26.1.42
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

I tried installing different versions of the supabase package but i got errors in all of them and I tried flutter clean but didnt help

Can you share your pubspec.yaml?

i added the pubspec.yaml code block

I see in your pubpsec.yaml file that many dependencies are commented out. Does this error appear only when adding the supabase dependency?

yes i intentionally commented the packages to see which one was causing the problem and i was left with supabase

Ever since I upgraded Android Studio to Ladybug version, I suffer from the same issue. When I create a new flutter project and run it in any emulator. It runs without any issues. but when I then add supabase_flutter dependency in pubspec.yaml and try to run the app again with no added code I get this path_provider error. I have tried so many proposed solutions from changing the gradle  and ndk versions to clearing cache and such but none helped.
